# Bizarre problem with 3 phase WYE system

Tags: three-phase

I have a weird problem with the electricity in my house. The house has a three phase municipal supply 400/230V WYE electrical system. The house is old and already I have had problems with water causing short circuits. Before anyone crucifies me, I am going to leave this house in a month or two and leave all the problems to the owner to fix before he rents it out again. But it is unlikely he will fix the current problem so I have to repair it myself to enjoy the luxury of electricity for the last days I will be living here. I am quite capable, but I just need a memory jog. The house is so badly wired that I have been unable to determine how they distributed the loads.

So, during the present rainy season, all of a sudden  on two phases I get 270 volts, the third phase is 230V (Phase to neutral). If I plug in a high load appliance such as a kettle on any phase, the other phases go ballistic, i.e. they either drop to below 200V or climb to 280V.

A while back I was a facilty supervisor and one problem we encontered was a failed neutral line on a WYE system. This puts 400V across all three phases (P-N). So I'm wondering if water has somehow gotten into the cables and caused this? It's obviously not a complete neutral disconnect otherwise I would measure 400V P-N on all of them.

Comment: hmm, do you know a person with access to a vde tester? sounds something is totally fu...ed up. If you are lucky, just a fuse/FI is damaged in your cabinet. Outside stuff like lamps are also possible sources of such errors. Is this error bound to one location, a room, or all over the house?

Comment: One of my LED security lights was grilled. probably due to getting 280 volts. I will go through with a fine toothcomb tomorrow. I'll also make a diagram, maybe it will help isolate the bad circuit.

Comment: Sounds to me like an open circuit neutral. If there are loads from all 3 phases to neutral that would explain why you measure "off" voltages, not 400V or the correct 230V from a rock solid neutral. How close you get to 230V depends on how well balanced the loads are : a kettle on one phase unbalances them.

Comment: @Brian Drummond A partially open neutral? Because of water infiltration maybe?

Comment: More likely a fully open neutral, with random loads providing an unstable "virtual neutral".

Comment: @BrianDrummond yes I also think so, I will have to go through the circuit tomorrow and I will report results here. Lucky it's cool tonight so I don't need the aircon.

Comment: @schnedan not likely here I'm in West Africa

Comment: It seems to be the neutral connection on the utility pole. Now I have to wait until the morning for them to come fix it. In the meantime I have been able to keep it going by carefully balancing the phases bit it's not easy.. Ive been withput electricity the whole day trying to find the problem.

Comment: The symptoms are typical of bad neutral connection somewhere , it might even be fully open, and relying on a neutral-earth connection in the meter box, this can potentially make all the plumbing on the house a "bit tingly to touch"  or worse. You need to pull the "pole fuse" to fix it otherwise you could end up with 230v across the neutral connector as you fiddle with it.

Comment: @BobT The utility showed up today (7 days after reporting the fault) and replaced the main breaker, after they left the fault is still present. So I disconnected the house from the main breaker and connected a kettle from neutral to phase, and lo and behold, the voltage dropped to 190, and rose to above 260 on the other two. So it's definitely between my meter and the pole. BTW they neutral-earth is normally at the nearest transformer here. Fingers crossed they come back tomorrow and fix it. I'm running off a small gasoline generator and it's not fun. Africa.

Comment: @raffles If you had a 5HP 3phase 230v star wound transformer, you could connect that up and get much a much better neutral. Here in Australia we have "multiply earthed neutrals" or MEN , although that may not help that much, a typical local earth resistance of 1ohm would see 20v of variation with 20A of load.

Comment: @BobT The utility guys haven't come back yet but you gave me an idea which has at least got me back on the grid, because the gasoline generator started playing up. I grounded the neutral wire at the service entrance and this has formed a bypass since I know the neutral is grounded at the transformer. Strange it is not the norm here as it should be. I'm willing to bet that the neutral has become disconnected where they connect the house to the overhead wires.

Comment: Yep probably the disconnect point, the neutral is at earth potential, so why bother to wrap the joint in rubber tape to keep the water out, and it doesn't really need to be that tight as it's not carrying any current on average. Unfortunately electricity is not an area to be complacent with. You will need 2 or 3 of "neutral stakes" to get the resistance below 1ohm, and dampen the ground locally, 3/4" water pipe might work, it has a fairly large surface area. I would not connect it to your existing earth as you would get a lot of potential on plumbing e.g. showers!!!

Comment: @BobT The earth I connected it to is separate. The house is at least 30m from the service entrance and has several rods for grounding next to it, I'm guessing, one for each phase. I suspect that the owner didn't want to pay for a 30 meter 5 core cable. This is how things are done in 3rd world countries. I might add another grounding rod to lower the resistance as I cant connect any high load appliances, it causes too much of an imbalance. But amazing that the utility ignores all of this.

Comment: Ah yes third world countries, ring up your utility and say you thought you saw "smoke coming from the transformer" ,  then they might look at it a bit sooner, Pole transformers are expensive to replace, especially if they catch fire and burn the pole.

Comment: A while back, I was walking my son to school one morning and noticed a bit of dead grass under a  power pole with a 200kVa transformer, on closer inspection there was some oil on the ground, so I rang the utility. The next morning there was shiny new transformer on top of the pole, all the dead grass was gone and new turf put down. But that's Australia, I think they wanted to fix it fast before someone complained of carcinogenic oil contamination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 4 interventions by the utility over a 2 month period, each time they they showed up the technician (a different one each time) denied that there could be a problem at the pole, even though I showed them an experiment that proved it was on the utility side. They changed the main breaker, which did have a burned contact but this wasn't the cause of the problem and the other times they made invalid excuses and left.

Eventually a friend contacted someone he knew higher up the ranks, and he showed up with an experienced technician. The tech climbed up the pole and remarked immediately that the neutral wire was burned, repaired it and problem solved in less than 30 minutes. The Third World works like this unfortunately. But I'm happy my electricity is back to normal.

[image]

Comment: Good that you are capable, made measurements and were persistent. The world is now a slightly less dangerous place.